# How to create a portal effect? Swift/Spritekit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create a Pacman style portal where if a player enters either the top or bottom of the screen they come out of the other side, but not on the sides.

I've created two bars ("portals") and set up a contact thing that says "If you touch this, set your Y value to either the top or right under the menu bar".  However, it gets stuck in an infinite loop, because it is just spawning right on top of the other portal (which I want so it looks like it is gliding in from the bottom) and getting sent back and forth.

I considered applying a number value to the balls, so that they only interact with the portals when they have a certain number that gets applied 0.0001 seconds after spawning. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func handleWallFlip() {
    // When the spaceship reaches the left wall, move it to the right wall and vica versa

    if spaceship.position.x < -10 {
        spaceship.removeAllActions()
        var movetoRightWall = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width, duration: 0)
        spaceship.runAction(movetoRightWall)
    } else if spaceship.position.x > self.frame.width + 10 {
        spaceship.removeAllActions()
        var movetoLeftWall = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: 0)
        spaceship.runAction(movetoLeftWall)
    }
}
```

the check happens at -10 or +10 and the placement puts it at 0, therefore there is a 10 unit distance so the infinite loop doesn't happen

Comment: Aweeesome! That is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: In doing this, the node is getting deleted once it goes off the screen. How do you prevent that?